# Flutter Custom Curved Button

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

Can anyone throw some light on how to implement this custom button? It should also be scalable from small to large both icons and fonts.

The image of the button which I want to create -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of Inkwell, CustomPaint and Text. Maybe it can be done with BoxDecoration instead of CustomPaint as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CustomClipper<Path>` to cut out the shape of the button and have a ElevatedButton or Container with Text in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use   `blobs: ^1.2.0` lib from this **[link](https://pub.dev/packages/blobs/install)**